# Jquery code runs one additional type every time it's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add new list item to my treeview.

Basically this should work as following:
Click on the icon with add-rule-btn class, modal (.add-new-rule) shows up. It has input field (#call-rule-name) and a button (#create-rule-btn). You enter the text and click the button and your text is added as another item at the bottom of a treeview.

Now, when I do it for the first time, it works fine. However if I want to add another one and I click the icon, enter text, click the button. The code runs twice and adds two items. When I try to do it again, the code runs tree times, and so on and so on.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Thanks in advance!

```
    $('.add-rule-btn').click(function(){
      var list;
      list = $(this).parent().next();
      $('#create-rule-btn').click(function(){
        var rule_name = $('#call-rule-name').val();
        list.append('<li class="treeview-animated-element"><span class="call-rule">' + rule_name + '</span></li>');
        $('.treeview-animated').mdbTreeview();
        $(".add-new-rule").modal("hide");
        $('#call-rule-name').val('');
      });
    });
```

Comment: your `$('#create-rule-btn').click` is inside the `$('.add-rule-btn').click` that's why when  make `var list` and it's also get the old data. and append it. make `$('#create-rule-btn').click` outside.

Comment: The reason I stored one function inside is because I need to get the list when I click the fist button and then use it when I click the second. If I move it outside I can't use the variable inside the other function,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to declared the var list outside. And because it's declared outside you can access and modify it inside.

```
.add-rule-btn
```

and

```
#create-rule-btn
```

Sample Code:

```
var list;

$('.add-rule-btn').click(function(){

  list = $(this).parent().next();

});

$('#create-rule-btn').click(function(){
  var rule_name = $('#call-rule-name').val();
  list.append('<li class="treeview-animated-element"><span class="call-rule">' + rule_name + '</span></li>');
  $('.treeview-animated').mdbTreeview();
  $(".add-new-rule").modal("hide");
  $('#call-rule-name').val('');
});
```

Comment: hehehe. happy to help you.